# How to import 100 gitea self-hosted repositories to Gitlab self-hosted community edition? Default import is broken

Tags: import, gitlab, gitea

I tried importing via default gitlab "import from gitea" and all I got - repositories with only FIRST commit, broken list of repositories from gitea (gitlab for some reason misplaces names of gitea repositories resulting in "name already taken").

Can I somehow export gitea repos into archive and import with 1 file or something? I'm afraid default gitlab import is not working for me, and our gitea server due to be disabled soon (migrating to server with better infrastructure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is, for each Gitea repository:

- clone it
- change the remote (`git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/...`) to a new empty GitLab project/repository, which can be [done from command line](https://coderwall.com/p/r7yh6g/create-a-new-gitlab-repo-from-the-command-line), using API or [`gitlab-cli`](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab/)
- `git push --mirror`

So you can script those steps, and loop over each of your Gitea repository that way.